# access in the template the selected value of a drop down list

Tags: angular

How can I access in the template, the selected value of a drop down list ?

```
  <div>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">{{ client.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- here I can access clients, but not the selected client -->
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the value of the select like that :

```
 <div>
    <select #selectedClient>
      <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">{{ client.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <!-- here I can access clients, but not the selected client -->
  <p>{{selectedClient.value}}</p>
```

hope it helps u :)

Comment: what do u mean by it does't work ? it gives you errors..or what ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way:

```
  <div>
    <select #dropdown (change)="onDropdownSelect(dropdown)">
      <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">{{ client.name }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

In the component:

```
  onDropdownSelect(elem){
    console.log(elem.value);
  }
```